# Proguard Build Android

Tags: android, android-proguard

`Error:Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstMethodRef cannot be cast to com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstInterfaceMethodRef`

Possible causes for this unexpected error include:

- Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.) Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
- The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem. Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
- Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Comment: are you using play services with proguard?

Comment: yes, am using latest version of play services i.e 9.0.1

Comment: Check the same issue - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=187483 .. and based on this may be you have to upgrad your proguard also.

Comment: this doesnt workout for me